# Using OR with a while loop

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to get two limits to or on the same while statement. Can this be done?

```cpp
while (digitalRead (home_limit)) {
```

This works for one(1) limit,
But when I try using two(2) limits  is does not work. I can't find the proper configuration. I tried this.

```cpp
while (digitalRead (home_limit1) || (home_limit2)) {
```

I also tried other combinations with no luck.
Does anyone know how to do an or (||) statement with a while digital read?

Comment: Firstly, when posting code select it and press ctrl+k to formatt it properly.

Try putting digitalRead in for both conditions and also specify what digitalRead value it should be

Comment: In `while(digitalRead(home_limit1) || home_limit2)`, the program will not evaluate `home_limit2` as long as `digitalRead(home_limit1)` return 1, is that what you want? do you really means `while(digitalRead(home_limit1) && home_limit2)`? If this is not what you want, you will need to edit your post to explain in plain English of what you want first.

Comment: I have a slide with two limits on it. One at each end of the slide. I'm doing experiments with this slide. At one time during programming I want home_limit1 to operate as a home switch for the CW direction. In a different program I want the slide to run in the opposite direction, CCW and now home_limit2 will now act as a home switch. I just wanted to know if I could or 2 digital reads together as shown above. while(digitalRead(home_limit1) || home_limit2). This way I could change the logic below the statement and make the motor run to the counterclockwise Direction and trip home_limit2.

Answer (score 2):

`digitalRead()` is a function. It takes one parameter (the pin number) and returns the state of that pin.  It's *that* return value that you want to OR with another. Which means you have to read the state of *both* pins, separately, and OR the results together:

```cpp
while (digitalRead(home_limit1) || digitalRead(home_limit2)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible to show me that code?Not sure how to use the return values of both to OR them in the program.

Comment: @BillPatton You mean aside from the example I've already given you?

Comment: Yes please. How would I go about accomplishing this in your estimation.

Comment: @BillPatton by using the code example that I already provided!

Comment: @BillPatton: Majenko's line of code in this answer is all you need. digitalRead(home_limit1) returns the state of this pin: a zero or a one. Likewise digitalRead(home_limit2) returns the state of that pin: a zero or a one. The while loop will be executed until both digitalReads return a zero.

Comment: Ok I see. I'll give that a try thank you very much.